# RingCentral API key

Tags: oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I am building an app needs to use the RingCentral API. It is server only (no UI) and it needs to be able to send SMS messages. I have names and numbers stored on the server and do not need access to any other features of RingCentral's API. Is there any way to get a normal API key for RingCentral (like the kind you get when using Google APIs), using OAuth in this situation seems a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

RingCentral supports the following OAuth 2.0 flows with links to the API documentation.

- [Authorization Code](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefAuthorization)
- [Implicit Grant](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefImplicitGrantType)
- [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefPasswordFlow)

A static API key is not supported at the moment.

Password grant is only supported for private apps (for use by your organization only), so if you are creating a public app (for use by other organizations), you will need to use the authorization code or implicit grant flows.

All 3 flows are supported in the [RingCentral JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js). [Other SDKs](https://developer.ringcentral.com/library/sdks.html) support Authorization Code and Password Grant.

Since you have a private `Server-only (No UI)` app, you can make the auth process less cumbersome by using password grant without refresh tokens. This way you can pass in the password on each request and not generate too many refresh tokens which can raise production issues with your app. To do this, do the following:

1. Use the password grant
2. set `refresh_token_ttl` to `-1` in the OAuth token request so no refresh token is generated

Comment: Is ringcentral support **Implicit Grant Type Flow**?

Comment: The RingCentral API supports Implicit Grant now. I've updated this answer to include it with a link to the documentation and JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***private*** `Server-only (No UI)` platform type, it will use `Password flow` and `Refresh Access Token`.
`Password flow` type app uses Oauth grant_type as password which are less cumbersome and more or less easy way in generating access_token
You just need to pass following headers in your Oauth call https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token:

```
"Accept":"application/json“
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded“
"Authorization",:"Basic <ClientID:ClientSecret in base 64>
```

In body, we need to pass the parameters in following way :

```
username=<account phone number>&password=<account password>&extension=<your extension>&grant_type=password
```

This is easy and less cumbersome  than you think.
If you don't need to generate refresh_token and want to get more simple response with access_token, you can pass `refresh_token_ttl=0` parameter in body.
There is nothing called normal API key in RingCentral. You will always have a client id and secret